# Save the string in reverse

Tags: c, string

Hello I'm trying to run the string until sign multiplication when I get multiplication sign I want to keep another string everything that was before the sign * to the + sign.
But unfortunately something is not working and the program does not work properly.

My code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int len = 8;
char str[8] = "2+3-5*7";
char str1[len];
int i,k = 0;

for(i = 0; i < len ; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == '*')
    {
        i--;
        while(str1[k] != '+')
        {
            str1[k] = str[i];
            k--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks to those who can solve my problem and explain it to me

Comment: [Fifth question](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3313154/user3313154?tab=questions) for one problem.  You should consider visiting the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read help on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop condition is using `str1` instead of `str`. Fix that, and see what happens if there is no `+` before the `*`...